# Utilizar comandos adb em App para android

Tags: android

Estou começando a usar algumas ferramentas de automação de testes, entre elas o Espresso, UI Automator ou mesmo um script de comandos em ADB. A minha dúvida é se é possível criar um aplicativo que rode comandos ADB para que ao inicia-lo ele execute os passos de um script feito, se sim, é necessário ter Root?

Comment: Poderia postar tal "script de comandos em ADB"? Muito provavelmente pode ser traduzido pra puro shell e executado nativamente no dispositivo. Alguns comandos não precisam de root, embora a maioria provavelmente sim.

Answer (score 0):

Não é possivel criar um app que rode esses comandos, você pode criar um script (Bash/Python) que execute uma sequencia de comandos ADB porém, deve executar na sua máquina.